# Erro: Não há suporte para a palavra-chave: 'provider'

Tags: c#, sql-server, connectionstring

Tenho de dar manutenção num sistema e ele esta com um problema que não consigo resolver há 1 mês por causa de uma falha de conexão.

> Não há suporte para a palavra-chave: 'provider'.
>   Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.ArgumentException: Não há suporte para a palavra-chave: 'provider'.
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de exceção abaixo.

String de conexão

```
<connectionStrings>    
  <add name="ApplicationServices" 
       connectionString="Server=SRVSQLDEALER\VDLSQLDB;User ID=monitor;Password=monitor;Database=dbRentabilidade_teste;Persist Security Info=True;Provider=SQLOLEDB" 
       providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

O que está errado?

Comment: posta o trecho do código que está utilizando estra string de conexão...

Comment: Por que você reverteu a edição? Fica complicado de ler do jeito que deixou... Além disso, a tag asp.net é desncessária dado o contexto, o problema é só na conexão ao banco, não tem relação com o ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

É só tirar esse `Provider` da string de conexão...

```
connectionString="Server=SRVSQLDEALER\VDLSQLDB;
User ID=monitor; Password=monitor; Database=dbRentabilidade_teste;Persist Security Info=True;"
```

Comment: Não funcionou e gerou outro erro ...

Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.
Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.

Detalhes da Exceção: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Comment: @ThiagoLopez Aí é outro problema... Não tem a ver com o problema da pergunta.

Comment: Se for o caso, finalize esta pergunta (já que parece ter resolvido o problema inicial) e abra outra.

Comment: Não foi finalizado pois não consegui fazer a conexão ainda. só gerou outro erro por nao ter resolvido o problema.

Comment: @ThiagoLopez O erro que você postou foi resolvido. O problema é claramente outra coisa e não tem nada relacionado com o erro postado.

Comment: Se não quer ajudar amigo, vou aguardar alguém com boa vontade.

Comment: Não é não querer ajudar, jovem. É só sobre como funciona o site. Mas você quer ficar nisso, boa sorte...

Comment: @ThiagoLopez O problema no seu comentário é diferente do problema proposto na pergunta. O problema com a string de conexão foi solucionado com a remoção do atributo `Provider`, o erro agora informado é que o motor do BD não consegue encontrar um elemento interno de gerenciamento `dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion` provavelmente porque seu BD não foi registrado com `aspnet_regsql.exe`. O ideal é abrir outra pergunta para esse problema. Mas pode tentar o **console de desenvolvedor do Visual Studio** e digitar `aspnet_regsql.exe` e seguir o assistente. Persistindo o erro abra uma nova pergunta.

Comment: OK, obrigado @AugustoVasques

Comment: @ThiagoLopez crie uma nova pergunta com o novo problema específico e coloque um link para essa pergunta para mostrar o que você tem feito até aqui.